# Awaiting database drop, then closing connection gives MongoExpiredSessionError

Tags: javascript, mongoose, jestjs

I am using Jest to run tests. I use the `afterAll()` function to drop the database, then closing the connection. However, I am receiving a "MongoExpiredSessionError".

Relevant code:

```
afterAll(async ()=>{
    await mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase((err)=>{console.error(err)});
    mongoose.disconnect();
});
```

Error:

```
MongoExpiredSessionError: Cannot use a session that has ended
        at applySession (/home/leemorgan/projects/js/api-easycv-work/node_modules/mongodb/src/sessions.ts:978:12)
        at Connection.command (/home/leemorgan/projects/js/api-easycv-work/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection.ts:519:31)
        at /home/leemorgan/projects/js/api-easycv-work/node_modules/mongodb/src/sdam/server.ts:365:14
        at Object.callback (/home/leemorgan/projects/js/api-easycv-work/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection_pool.ts:513:7)
        at ConnectionPool.processWaitQueue (/home/leemorgan/projects/js/api-easycv-work/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection_pool.ts:689:25)
        at /home/leemorgan/projects/js/api-easycv-work/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection_pool.ts:357:33
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
      [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
    }
```

It seems to me that `disconnect` should not run until the database is dropped because I am awaiting. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: Not used `mongoose`,  but if your using `await`, why are you using a `callback`?.   You might find the API will not return a promise if you supply one.

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. I don't know why I did that. Completely overlooked it. Thanks a lot. If you want to add it as an answer then I will accept it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often dual use API's that are Promise based & callback based flip between returning a promise based on if you supply a callback.

So ->

```
    await mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase((err)=>{console.error(err)});
```

In the above a callback was supplied, the API then thought you was using callback variant so didn't bother wrapping inside a Promise, this then causes the `await` to do nothing.